# Is “funner” a word or not?

Tags: grammar

I tried searching it up and it said yes “funner” is a word, but when I ask teacher they said no it isn’t a word, anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1):

*Fun* is in reasonably common use as a adjective; but the comparative *funner* is rare, and some would say that it is not standard English.

There is one instance of it in the Oxford English Dictionary, from 1996, "not one of the funner moments". But notice 1) that this is from a humorous work, and may be deliberately using a non-standard form; and 2) that it is within the idiomatic construction "not one of the X-er Ys", where it is recognisable as a comparative by the syntax.

There are 1042 instances of "funner" in the iWeb corpus, so it is not common, but is used.

Comment: Thanks for the help!